# How to extract text using Regular expression (RegEx)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with regular expressions in JavaScript.

I have the following string.

```
var str = "SOme TEXT #extract1$ Some more text #extract2$ much more text #extract3$ some junk";
```

I want to extract all the text between `#` and `$` into an array or object.

Final output would be:

```
var result = [extract1,extract2,extract3]
```

extract1, extract2,extract3 can contain any characters like `_,@,&,*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript Regular expressions' exec method.

```
var regex = /\#([^\$]+)\$/g,
    match_arr,
    result = [],
    str = "some #extract1$ more #extract2$ text #extract3$ some junk";
while ((match_arr = regex.exec(str)) != null)
{
   result.push(match_arr[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 2):

Regex for you will be like `#(?<extract>[\s\S]*?)\$`

Named group '**extract**'will contain the values you want.

As Alex mentioned, if javascript doesnt support named group, we can use numbered group. So modified regex will be `#([\s\S]*?)\$` and desired values will be in group number 1.

Comment: nice touch with the [\s\S]. how does it perform against [^\$] ?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky, certainly [^\$] is faster than [\s\S]

Comment: [JavaScript doesn't have named capturing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex). Why do you escape `#`? Also, why the `?` after the `*`?

Comment: @alex, I dont know anything about JavaScript, I am from C# world. We can use numbered group instead of named groups.

Comment: @Shekhar Also, I understand the `?` now. Ungreedy. How did I forget that?

Comment: @alex the `*?` means its a non-greedy `*` which means it will capture as little as possible. EG a regex of `.*b` on a string `"aaaababa"` will capture `"aaaabab"` but a non greedy `.*?b` will capture `"aaaab"`. **EDIT** beat me to it alex. ;)

Comment: @James Yeah, I somehow forgot (though I use it probably 5 times a week). See comment above :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = str.match(/#(.+?)\$/gi);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/WXPjA/).