# Correct Regular Expression match containing optional substrings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following set of strings:

```
some_param[name] 
some_param_0[name]
```

I wish to capture **some_param**, **0**, **name** from them. 
My regex knowledge is pretty weak. I tried the following, but it doesn't work for both cases.

```
/^(\D+)_?(\d{0,2})\[?(.*?)\]?$/.exec("some_param_0[name]") //works except for the trailing underscore on "some_param"
```

What would be the correct regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^(\w+?)_?(\d{0,2})(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\])?$/
```

`(\w+?)` uses a [non-greedy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) to capture the identifier part without any trailing `_`.

`_?` is greedy so will beat the `+?` in the previous part.

`(\d{0,2})` will capture 0-2 digits.  It is greedy, so even if there is no `_` between the identifier and digits, this will capture digits.

`(?:...)?` makes the square bracketed section optional.

`\[([^\[\]]*)\]` captures the contents of a square bracketed section that does not itself contain square brackets.

```
'some_param_0[name]'.match(/^(\w+?)_(\d{0,2})(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\])?$/)
```

produces an array like:

```
["some_param_0[name]",  // The matched content in group 0.
 "some_param",          // The portion before the digits in group 1.
 "0",                   // The digits in group 2.
 "name"]                // The contents of the [...] in group 3.
```

Note that the non-greedy quantifier might interact strangely with the bounded repetition in `\d{0,2}`.

```
'x1234[y]'.match(/^(\w+?)_?(\d{0,2})(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\])?$/)
```

yields

```
["x1234[y]","x12","34","y"]
```

Comment: I think he wants to remove the trailing underscore.. am I right? I tried with `/^([a-zA-Z_]+)(?:_(\d{0,2}))?(?:\[([^\[\]]*)\])?$/` but it looks like it doesn't work (at least, in Python)

Comment: @redShadow, the RegExp in the OP leaves it out of capturing group 1, so I assumed the poster wanted it in.

Comment: Sorry, In the code comment I mentioned that I ideally wanted the trailing underscore to be ignored ("some_param" instead of "some_param_"). Should've made it clear in the question.

Comment: @fenderplayer, redShadow, Edited to make sure that `_` is not captured in group 1.

Comment: @MikeSamuel better to use `(?:_(\d+))?`, or you'll cut out the underscore in, e.g., `some_param_[name]`..

Comment: (I love infinite discussions on how to finely tune regular expressions.. you always end up learning something)

Answer (score 1):

Got it! (taking from Mike's answer):

```
/^(\D+)(?:_(\d+))?(?:\[([^\]]*)\])/

'some_param[name]' => ('some_param', None, 'name')
'some_param_0[name]' => ('some_param', '0', 'name')
```

(at least, in Python it works)

**UPDATE:** A little extra I wrote fiddling with it, by making the result cleaner by using named groups:

```
^(?P<param>\D+)(?:_(?P<id>\d+))?(?:\[(?P<key>[^\]]*)\])
```

**UPDATE:**

- Named groups are not supported in JavaScript.
- I've made some other tinkering with this regex. All the tests can be found here http://stuff.hackzine.org/stackoverflow/8497781_test-js-regex.html
- The ultimate regexp I came out with is: `/^([A-Za-z_]+)(?:_(\d+))?(?:\[([^\]]*)\])?$/`, that seems to work in a lot of cases.

Comment: Cool! Will check out named groups.

Comment: @fenderplayer, JavaScript does not have named groups.

Comment: I am testing named groups in javascript too; it looks like the syntax is different from the Python one; keep tuned as I'll write here when I find out how to use them in JS too.. :)

Comment: Ok, it looks like there is no way to do that in JS.. :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369

Answer (score 0):

Please ,check the follwing regexp "(\w+)_(\d)[(\w+)]" yo can test it @ http://rubular.com/