# Regex JavaScript. Parse a log file with current Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have used Regex in C#. How do I use this type of Regex in Javasript. This type of regex works in C#.

I have the following Regex:

```
(?<Month>[A-Za-z]{3}) (?<Date>[0-9]{2}) (?<Hour>[0-9]{2}):(?<Minutes>[0-9]{2}):(?<Seconds>[0-9]{2}) (?<ComputerName>[A-Za-z0-9\-\ ]+): (?<KernalTime>[0-9\.\[\]\ ]+) (?<Message>[A-Za-z\(\)\.\ ]+)
```

to Parse the Following Line (All Lines are similar):

```
Nov 24 14:24:31 Dell-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
```

In javascript i used the following code.

```
matchRegexParse: function () {



   var myString = "Nov 24 14:24:31 Dell-Inspiron-N5110 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel";
    var myRegexp = new RegExp(
        "(?<Month>[A-Za-z]{3}) (?<Date>[0-9]{2}) (?<Hour>[0-9]{2}):(?<Minutes>[0-9]{2}):(?<Seconds>[0-9]{2}) (?<ComputerName>[A-Za-z0-9\-\ ]+): (?<KernalTime>[0-9\.\[\]\ ]+) (?<Message>[A-Za-z0-9\(\)\.\ \-\:]+)",
        "gi");

    var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
    alert(match);
},
```

I get the following Error (See Attached Image):

[image]

**EDIT (ERROR AS TEXT):**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/(?<Month>[A-Za-z]{3}) (?<Date>[0-9]{2}) (?<Hour>[0-9]{2}):(?<Minutes>[0-9]{2}):(?<Seconds>[0-9]{2}) (?<ComputerName>[A-Za-z0-9\-\ ]+): (?<KernalTime>[0-9.\[\]\ ]+) (?<Message>[A-Za-z0-9\(\)\.\ \-\:]+)/`: Invalid group

Comment: To start with you should use a regex literal to avoid the escaping (that you forget). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware JavaScript does not support named groups:

[Named capturing groups in JavaScript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex)

You can either convert to numeric-index groups by removing the `<Angle-Bracket-Parts>`

```
var re = /([A-Za-z]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}) ([A-Za-z0-9\-\ ]+): ([0-9\.\[\]\ ]+) ([A-Za-z0-9\(\)\.\ \-\:]+)/gi
```

Which will mean that you can only access the captured information by numeric offsets:

```
var match = re.exec(myString);
console.log( match[1] ) // Nov 24
```

or use something like:

http://xregexp.com/