# Javascript: Named Capture Groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match an expression and extract values from it using named groups.

Lets say this is my string:

```
var str = 'element=123'
```

So i want to match it using regex and extract the element and value.

I know how to do it is c#, I am trying to figure it out in JS.

This is my regex:

```
new RegExp(/^(<element>[A-Za-z0-9])+=[A-Za-z0-9]+$/);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex

Comment: If you have a set pattern on the string 'str', then you can use slit by ('=') to read key and value separately. e.g. str.split('=')[0] , str.split('=')[1]; , Just an short method if you want to avoid Regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### JavaScript does not support named capture groups.

You will have to use numbered groups.

For instance:

```
var myregex = /([^=]+)=(.*)/;
var matchArray = myregex.exec(yourString);
if (matchArray != null) {
    element = matchArray[1];
    id = matchArray[2];

}
```

**Option 2: XRegExp**

The alternate regex library for JavaScript [XregexP](http://xregexp.com/syntax/) supports named captures as well as other important regex features missing from JS regex, such as lookbehinds.

Comment: obsolete answer.

Comment: no it's not obsolete - a lot of major browsers still do not support named capture groups even though JS technically does.

Comment: Yes, it is obsolete. The JavaScript language supports named capture groups, even if some browsers don't. Currently, only IE fails to support this. See the compatibility chart at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: If it wasn't then it is now: https://caniuse.com/?search=named%20capture

Answer (score 36):

Now, with ES2018, RegExp named capture groups are actually possible.

Here's an example already working in Chrome 64 (soon to be available also in Safari).

```
const isoDateExpression = /(?<year>[0-9]{4})-(?<month>[0-9]{2})-(?<day>[0-9]{2})/;

let match = isoDateExpression.exec('1999-12-31');
console.log(
    match.groups.year, // 1999
    match.groups.month, // 12
    match.groups.day, // 31
)
```

Syntax reference:
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups

Firefox <del>haven't decided yet</del>, but here's an entry in Mozilla's issue tracker:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362154

**Edit**: Named capture groups are now implemented in major browsers and available since Chrome 62 (2018), Firefox 78 (2020) and Safari 11.3 (2018).