# Regex not working in FireFox, how to make this Regex working in FireFox?

Tags: javascript

I have the following `regex`

```
string.match(/(?<notification_ID>\d+)/g)
```

In Chrome this works fine, but in FireFox this throws an exception

> SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

I tried the solution given by [JavaScript regular expression exception (Invalid group)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200157/javascript-regular-expression-exception-invalid-group) by removing the `?` mark.

So my Regex became

```
$location.path().match(/(<notification_ID>\d+)/g)
```

However, now it returns `null`.

What I want is to return an notification ID based on a string

Eg. https://example.com/here-comes-a-path/#!/notification-14 should return `14`

How can I make the regex so it will work among all browsers?

---

If you are using Chrome this snippet will work

```js
var string = 'https://example.com/here-comes-a-path/#!/notification-14';

console.log(string.match(/(?<notification_ID>\d+)/g))
```

Comment: Why not use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200197/2025923). `str.match(/notification-(\d+)/)[1]`.

Comment: Your regex only matches numbers anywhere in the string. Try with string `htt111p://example.com/1111/....`.

Comment: The FireFox version you are using might not be supporting [Named Capturing Group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367369/2025923) while Chrome is supporting.
[Browser Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).  [Further Reading](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex like this would work:

```
notification-(\d+)
```

It matches `notification-` and then captures one or more digits in `(\d+)`.

```js
const regex = /notification-(\d+)/
const string = "https://example.com/here-comes-a-path/#!/notification-14"

const matches = string.match(regex);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = 'https://example.com/here-comes-a-path/#!/notification-14';

console.log(string.match(/notification-(\d+)/g))
```

Thats what you have to use so it works in all browsers. Named groups are new to JS as of ES2018, see [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-named-groups).

Firefox has not implemented it yet, see [their bug report here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362154).

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24859190/6622577) for more informations.