# Regular expression gives invalid group error

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to find a string between space and colon. For that I have the below regex expression which is giving me an 'invalid group name' error (same in python also):

```
(?<content>[^ :]*:$)
```

Here is [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/gB4gN3/1#javascript)

Same Expression has no error in PHP
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB4gN3/1#pcre).

Javascript expression :-

```
var reg = new RegExp("(?<content>[^ :]*):$", "g");`
```

Can anybody tell me why should be this?

**Edit:**

**Sample Input:**

```
DefVariable   変数名：配列「n]
DefVariable  変数名：string
DefVariable   変数名：int
DefVariable   変数名：decimal
DefVariable   変数名：日付
DefVariable   変数名：時間
```

**Sample Output:**

Could be match **変数名：** from each line where instead of **変数名** any character will come.

Comment: How do you call the result of your regex?

Comment: @Docteur its giving error on  var reg = new RegExp("(?[^ :]*):$", "g");`  statement because of that its not proceed to next statement. the call is before result calling statement.

Comment: Please see my demo with updated input. It should work for you!

Comment: @Grundy: This is not just named capturing group issue, the anchor was not correctly used, too. There are several issues here, I believe.

Comment: @stribizhev, methinks main problem in OP _regex expression which is giving me an 'invalid group name' error_ and _Can anybody tell me why should be this?_ so it seems exactly duplicated

Comment: @Grundy: I know, but then came the edits. Edits usually turn a question into some different question than at the beginning.

Comment: @stribizhev in edit simple provided input and output without diffrent question :-)

Comment: @stribizhev anyway for marked duplicate just mine vote not enough

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is incorrect :

```
(?<content>[^ :]*:$)
```

A `(?<group>)` notation doesn't exist in Javascript. Only `(numbered group)`, `(?:non capturing)` and lookarounds. If I understand correctly, you need this :

```
\s([^ :]*):$
```

See demo [here](http://regexr.com/3at65).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [named capturing groups in JavaScript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex). You will have to use just a numbered one, like this:

```
 ([^ ：]*：)
```

Also, you are using `$` (end of string/line) anchor in your regex, but in your examples, there are still some characters after the full-width colon. Thus, the regex won't match even if you remove the named capture.

Explanation:

- - A literal space
- `([^：]*：)` - A capturing group with a string that has no spaces and full-width colons, 0 or more size and `：`, a full-width colon
- `$` - End of string/line.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ5nU3/7)

In PHP, [named groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) exist., and you can use `(?<name>...)` or `(?'name')`. In Python, they also exist, but they are written in a bit different way: `(?P<tag>...)`

Comment: Thanks for answer. But its not check string with preceding whitespcae. I am trying line [whitespace]string[colon] format.

Comment: So, you mean this ` ([^ :]*):$`? Please add sample input and sample output you want to get in your question.

Comment: Edited: please check https://regex101.com/r/kZ5nU3/6