# Regex: Can I name my matches and get them as an associative array?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, associative-array

Ususually you get your matches somewhat like this:

```
var myString = "Hello Alex, I am John";
matches = myString.match(/"Hello (.+) I am (.+)/);
console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```

But is it possible in javscirpt to name your matches within the regex?

Somewhat like this:

```
var myString = "Hello Alex, I am John";
matches = myString.match(/"Hello ([hisName].+) I am ([yourName].+)/);
console.log(match.hisName);
console.log(match.yourName);
```

Comment: JS regex engine doesn't have named groups.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex

Comment: Oh, it's called named capturing groups.. I didn't know that. My question can be marked as duplicate then.

Comment: @Forivin I was going to add an answer but it was marked as duplicate. BTW, I've added it to the whole Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex/32271196#32271196

Comment: @Forivin Maybe that simple function is enough for you ;P