# Regex using Dart lang

Tags: regex, dart, dart-pub

I'm building a log parser in dart. How can I use dart regex library to retrieve matching values.

Using this [link](https://regex101.com/) to check my regex, everything is ok wih the following :

- Regex : `(?<suffix>^.*m)(?<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}) (?<level>[^\s]+) (?<message>.*)`
- Input : [0m[31m22:25:57,366 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."bad.war".

Entering these values will give you : suffix, time , level and message

I'm not able to use my regex with the dart library.

Comment: What would be a valid value?

Comment: Try http://regexr.com/ Dart only supports what JS RegExp supports to be xxxToJS transpilable.

Comment: Use numbered capture groups: [`^(.*m)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}) ([^\s]+) (.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rR3xG8/1) and access them with number indices.

Comment: Thank You @GünterZöchbauer for editing the original answer.  The valid value will be suffix=[0m[31m , time=22:25:57,366 , level=error, message=....

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How to use numbered capture groups with dart Regex ?

Comment: I am on it right now. Actually, if you expect multiple matches, use [`allMatches`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.18.1/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html), get each match and access with `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` and `[4]`.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Named groups are now supported. https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/RegExpMatch/namedGroup.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When running Dart in a browser, it uses the browser's regex engine, and [if it supports named capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367407/3832970) they will be supported. If not, they won't. When running your code in Flutter, or standalone Dart, [`namedGroup`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/RegExpMatch/namedGroup.html) works as you'd expect.

Use numbered capturing groups and access them by their indices:

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"^(.*m)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}) ([^\s]+) (.*)");
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rR3xG8/1)

In Dart, try something like this:

```
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"^(.*m)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2},\d{1,3}) ([^\s]+) (.*)");
String s = "[0m[31m22:25:57,366 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit.\"bad.war\"";
Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(s);
for (Match match in matches) {
  print("${match.group(1)}\n");
  print("${match.group(2)}\n");
  print("${match.group(3)}\n");
  print("${match.group(4)}\n");
}
```

See this [DartPad demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/46930fd48dc1bf3a4151d5fa15566732)

Comment: Thank You. it's ok. I've created a dartpad sample to share the solution https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0bd2244aa9e93c300282d269f2eda0be

Comment: Oh, I have not seen the comment before I posted my example :) Glad you found a way quicker. I just had some problems with getting the demo work on the Dart pad.

Comment: This is no longer the case. Named groups are now supported. https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/RegExpMatch/namedGroup.html

Comment: @ScottHyndman For some reason, named groups are not working in DartPad. Also, according to [*Strings and regular expressions*](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/dart-core-library.html#strings-and-regular-expressions) documentation section, Dart regex is based on [ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10) that does not support named groups (their support is introduced in ECMAScript 2018). Something here does not "click".

Comment: Ah. When Dart is running in the browser it's likely using the browser's regex engine. When running in Flutter, or standalone Dart, namedGroups work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, as Scott Hyndman explains in a comment, this is now supported with RegExpMatch.
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

This does appear to be working in DartPad now (with dart 2.4.0 at least).
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/de5fafc572ebb786c9b4791229c65a9b

Comment: No it's not working in dartpad. It throws an error in 2.4.1.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, if you try the dartpad link provided does it work?
It works for me.

Comment: Hi Gav, it worked here.