# RegExp Match returning whole word not groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm currently trying to validate strings in a text box with this code:

```
 $scope.regexArray = ["Alarm id (?<serverNumber>\d+) has been received from video server number (?<alarmNumber>\d+).", "Alarm id (?<serverNumber>\d+) has been received from video server number (?<alarmNumber>\d+)."];

    $scope.validTextBox = false; 
    $scope.userInput = "";
    $scope.validateExpression = function () {

        angular.forEach($scope.regexArray, function (value, key) {

            var test = $scope.userInput.match(value);

            console.log(test);
        })
    }
```

The output of `test` is this:

```
["Alarm id 4 has been received from video server number 4", index: 0, input: "Alarm id 4 has been received from video server number 4", groups: undefined]

0: "Alarm id 4 has been received from video server number 4"
groups: undefined
index: 0
input: "Alarm id 4 has been received from video server number 4"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I can’t seem to access any capture groups. Trying `test[0]` doesn’t work.

Comment: You have no capturing groups in the pattern. A capturing group is a pair of unescaped parentheses. Like `"Alarm id (\\d+) has been received from video server number (\\d+)"`

Comment: I think the problem with your patterns is that you are using **named capturing groups** which is experimental and might not be supported in your browser.
The solution to this is using only **numbered capturing groups**.

Comment: A brief explanation of this issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367407/8371135)

Answer (score 1):

Changes to make:

- `(?<serverNumber>\d+)` is not valid JavaScript regexp syntax for a capturing group. JavaScript only understands anonymous capture groups such as `(\d+)`. As demonstrated further down, you can give names to matches by storing them in variables after extracting them from the match array with `[]`.
- It's not necessary to make the code work in this case, but your code will be clearer if you change your `regexArray` to contain actual regexes `/…/` instead of strings `"…"` that will be converted to regexes by `.match`.

The following code demonstrates successful matches:

```js
var regexArray = [
  /Alarm id (\d+) has been received from video server number (\d+)./,
  /Alarm id (\d+) has been received from video server number (\d+)./
];

var userInput = "Alarm id 1000 has been received from video server number 6.";

regexArray.forEach(function(value) {
  var matches = userInput.match(value);
  console.log(matches);
});
```

To get specific matches from the `matches` array, you can add this code:

```
var alarmId = matches[1];
var serverId = matches[2];
```

Note that `alarmId` and `serverId` will be strings after the above. If you want to convert them to numbers, so that the extracted strings `"012"` and `"12"` would be treated the same, add [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var alarmNumber = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
var serverNumber = parseInt(matches[2], 10);
```