# Typescript cannot parse named groups in regex

Tags: regex, typescript, webpack

I have a code line

```
regex = /^(?<aa>[0-9]{2})-(?<bb>[0-9]{6})-(?<cc>[0-9]{6})-(?<d>[0-9])$/;
```

And typescript (or is it webpack?) complains:

```
Module parse failed: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /^(?<aa>[0-9]{2})-(?<bb>[0-9]{6})-(?<cc>[0-9]{6})-(?<d>[0-9])$/: Invalid group (18:23)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

It seems to be a problem with the named groups. This is a valid regex in javascript.

I'm using typescript `2.9.2`

I strongly prefer using named groups. What can I do to make them compile?

Comment: This seems to work on the typescript of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z85dmrcL/), we need more information ...

Comment: So it's probably the version of typescript that is wrong. Can I change typescript version in jsfiddle? @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy BTW, wrapping expression in a string (`new RegExp("..")`) somewhat helps as it seems to switches off compile time validation. Still testing..

Comment: I don't think you can change typescript version in jsfiddle, I'm looking into it too. Using `RegExp()` is a good idea, do keep us updated :-) I can't seem to be able to reproduce, I'm sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is actually not a valid regular expression in javascript according to https://regexr.com/. And Firefox and Edge.

Or rather, it depends on the browser. Support for named groups has been added to ES2018. So your mileage might vary.

See http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ for compatibility.

Typescript compiler is not the one throwing the error it's your webpack module loader. I would try setting the target to ES2018 and see if that works.

Alternatively see the answer about array destructuring on [Named capturing groups in JavaScript regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex) .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately transpiling the regex itself is not supported by Typescript itself. See [issue #24531](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24531).

If you're using Babel aswell in your build chain, consider [`plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex.html)