# How can I express a list containing named groups in regex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, typescript

I currently have the following regex:

```
P:(?<ParentName>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)-(?<ParentAge>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)
C:(?<Child>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)
```

which matches with

```
P:Bob-30
C:Jane
```

However, I would like be able to express a regex matching with:

```
P:Jack-35
C:John
C:Marie
```

I tried this by adding []+ arround the second part:

```
P:(?<ParentName>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)-(?<ParentAge>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)
[C:(?<Child>[A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_]+)]+
```

However this doesn't work and gives an error: 'unmatched parenthesis )'for the last parenthesis.

Anyone an idea how I can express this?

Thank you!

**Update**
The problems seems to be the [] inside [].
Working regex for only 1 "C:.."-line:

```
P:(?<ParentName>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)-(?<ParentAge>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
C:[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\n
```

Not working regex for multiple "C:.."-lines:

```
P:(?<ParentName>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)-(?<ParentAge>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)
[C:[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\n]+
```

The first [ in the second line matches with the first ], while it should be the second ].

Comment: JavaScript does not support named groups.

Comment: @Pointy ECMAScript 2018 compliant JS regex does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I remembered that :) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex) However it's not widely supported

Comment: Thanks! but the named groups work ;). it only gives problems when trying to express them inside a list

Comment: Those commas in your `[ ]` subexpressions seem odd to me; you don't need commas to separate character ranges, and the commas will be taken as part of the allowed character set.

Comment: Also the `C:` thing involves `[ ]` inside `[ ]`; what do you intend that to mean?

Comment: Woops, you're right about the commas. Updated my question with more details about the []. @Pointy

Comment: Should C:John and C:Marie in the same group as Child like this: https://regex101.com/r/IM0HIn/2

Comment: I don't know of any regex syntax that allows nested `[ ]` groups; I can't even imagine what that would mean. A `[ ]` subexpression matches a single character (or not).

Answer (score 1):

To get C:John and C:Marie in the `Child` group, you could capture a repeating group inside the child group:

```
(?<Child>(?:C:[A-Za-z0-9,_]+(?:\s|$))+)
```

- `(?<Child>` Named group
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `C:[A-Za-z0-9,_]+(?:\s|$)` Match C: followed by any listed in the character class and then match either a whitespace char or the end of the string
- `)+` Close capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close named group

Your pattern might look like:

```
P:(?<ParentName>[A-Za-z0-9,_]+)-(?<ParentAge>[A-Za-z0-9,_]+)\s*(?<Child>(?:C:[A-Za-z0-9,_]+(?:\s|$))+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8vI4WD/1)

Note that the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refshorthand.html) can be updated to `[A-Za-z0-9,_]+` where you can list each charcter one time.