# Firefox gives SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

Tags: regex, reactjs, firefox, regex-group

I have few regular expression used for form validation and I noticed that my project is not accessible through firefox as it shows nothing! but give the error in the console, `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`

nicRegex is checking for National Identity Card in my country. Format should be `937962723V` or `937962723X` or any 11 digit number according to the current format.

phoneRegex is to check phone numbers with my country code. `94121212121` or `0762323232`

`const nicRegex = /^(?:19|20)?\d{2}(?:[01235678]\d\d(?<!(?:000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)))\d{4}(?:[vVxX])$/;`

Comment: You could try each of them in the console to find out which is wrong

Comment: You should at least know *which* REGEX is problematic. That will be denoted by the line number attached to the error.

Comment: It doesn't give any particular line number but bundle.js:1:34. of bundle.js

Comment: @Utkanos I found the culprit. It's `const nicRegex = /^(?:19|20)?\d{2}(?:[01235678]\d\d(?<!(?:000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)))\d{4}(?:[vVxX])$/;`

Comment: `nicRegex` contains a *negative lookbehind* - this is not supported in FF.

Comment: @AlexK. Any suggestions to  get this solved?

Comment: I edited my question including the problematic regex

Comment: Well you would need to rewrite it so that it didn't need to use one, the way you actually do that depends on the rules of the format your trying to validate. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent

Comment: That was helpful @AlexK. I rewrote a simple regrex and it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The negative lookbehind (not currently supported in Safari) is used here to restrict the previous three digits. This restriction can be performed equally well with a negative lookahead, just it needs to be placed *before* the 3-digit pattern:

```
(?:[0-35-8]\d\d(?<!(?:000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)))
```

should look like

```
(?!000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)[0-35-8]\d\d
```

Note the non-capturing groups are redundant here, I removed them, and `[01235678]` = `[0-35-8]`.

The final regex looks like

```
/^(?:19|20)?\d{2}(?!000|500|36[7-9]|3[7-9]\d|86[7-9]|8[7-9]\d)[0-35-8]\d\d\d{4}[vVxX]$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HUdynV/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A19%7C20)%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D(%3F!000%7C500%7C36%5B7-9%5D%7C3%5B7-9%5D%5Cd%7C86%5B7-9%5D%7C8%5B7-9%5D%5Cd)%5B0-35-8%5D%5Cd%5Cd%5Cd%7B4%7D%5BvVxX%5D%24):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR; Use named capture groups with caution (or just don't use them)

For me, it was because I thought I'd be clever and try to used named capture groups in my regex... Firefox punished me.

**Doesn't work:** `/(?<text>[a-z]+)/`

**Does work:** `/([a-z]+)/`