# ReactJs: SyntaxError - invalid regexp group in firefox

Tags: reactjs, regex, syntax-error, aws-sdk

In my react application, I have an import module statement like this.

```
import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
```

However, in Firefox I cannot load the application as it returns the below error.

> SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

This is not an issue in other browsers.

I found out that the above import statement returns this error. I believe this due to "@" sign. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox gives SyntaxError: invalid regexp group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774080/firefox-gives-syntaxerror-invalid-regexp-group)

Comment: No. I don't have any regex in my application

Comment: Firefox should not throw this error unless some invalid RegExp pattern is defined in that import. Is your FF up-to-date?