# Unable to access regex value using different name

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I've the below Regex expression,

```
const regex = new RegExp('<(.*)>' + text + '<(.*)>');
renderer.setProperty(node, 'innerHTML', node.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<$1>' + replaceText + '<$2>'));
```

Instead of using `'<$1>'` and `'<$2>'`, I need to use `'<$open>'` & `'<$close>'`

When I tried changing it's not working as expected.

How can it be done ?

Comment: what do you mean by `$open` and `$close` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex

Comment: `new RegExp('<(?<open>.*?)>' + text + '<(?<close>.*?)>')` and  `'<$<open>>' & '<$<close>>'` in the replacement

Answer (score 0):

You seem to target ECMAScript 2018+ JS environment.

You may use `(?<name>pattern)` to define the [named capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367369/named-capturing-groups-in-javascript-regex) in the pattern and **`$<name>` named replacement backreferences** in the replacement pattern to refer to the strings captured with the named groups.

You may also enhance the code a bit using

```
const regex = new RegExp('<(?<open>[^>]+)>' + text.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + '<(?<close>[^>]+)>');
renderer.setProperty(node, 'innerHTML', node.innerHTML.replace(regex, '<$<open>>' + replaceText.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$') + '<$<close>>'));
```

**NOTES**

- `(?<open>[^>]+)` matches and captures the open tag into `open` named group and `(?<close>[^>]+)` captures the close tag into `close` named group with `[^>]+` pattern: 1 or more chars other than `>`
- `text.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` is used to escape any special chars in `text`
- `replaceText.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$')` is required to correctly handle `$1` like literal strings in the replacement text.