# Javascript regex: How to avoid a capturing group becoming "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

If I want to capture e.g. text that is either in round brackets or square brackets and use this regular expression:

```
\[(.+)\]|\((.+)\)
```

I get for the example "[test]" the results "test" and "undefined" and for "(test)" the results "undefined" and "test".
How can I manage to get only "test" as result?

(This regex is only an example, my actual regex is more complex but with the same problem.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5367369/2864740 - named capture groups (2018+ only!), or post-manipulation.

Comment: Without a branch reset feature, all you can do is remove the undefined value from the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use look-ahead to match either option first, then capture again in a second pass, you can get the match into a single capture.

The simplest approach uses other captures too:

```
(?=\[(.+?)\]|\((.+?)\))[(\[](\1\2)[)\]]
```

Works by: Matching either `[...]` or `(...)` as look-ahead, capturing the text between the delimiters into a capture 1 or 2. Then it captures the same text again, ignoring the delimiter, by backreferencing `\1\2`, relying on back-reference to a non-participating match to match the empty string.
This way, the same string is captured into capture 3, which is always participating.

It's probably fairly efficient. The back-reference to *the same position* should match in no time.

If that's not good enough, and you want a RegExp with *precisely* one capture, which is the text between `[..]` or `(..)`, then I'd try look-*behinds* instead:

```
[(\[](.+?)(?:(?=\))(?<=\(\1)|(?=\])(?<=\[\1))
```

It matches a `[` or `(`, then tries to find a capture after it which, is followed by either `)` or `]`, and then it does a backwards check to see if the leading delimiter was the matching `(` or `[` respectively.

Unlikely to be as efficient, but only matches `(...)` and `[...]` and captures what's between them in the single capture.
If the look-behind back-reference to the same position is efficient (not as guaranteed, but possible), it's potentially not bad.
If it's not efficient, it may do a lot of looking back (but only when seeing a possible end-`)` or -`]`).

It can also be converted to a RegExp which matches only the text you want, so "capture zero" is the result (as well as capture 1, which it uses internally), by matching the leading `[` or `(` with a look-behind:

```
(?<=[(\[])(.+?)(?:(?=\))(?<=\(\1)|(?=\])(?<=\[\1))
```

(Look-behinds, and -aheads, really is the gift that keeps giving when it comes to RegExp power. Both look-ahead and look-behind allows you to match the same sub-string more than once, using different RegExps, and even allows the later ones refer to captures from earlier matches.)

Answer (score -1):

If the specific group numbers that get captured don't matter, just the text they contain, I think the easiest thing is to just filter the match afterwards to remove the undefined groups:

```js
for (const match of ' [foo] (bar) '.matchAll(/\[(.+)\]|\((.+)\)/g)) {
  const [, text] = match.filter(m => m !== undefined);
  console.log(text);
}
```