# Regular expression help for a date (python+

Tags: python, regex

im trying to create an expression that matches 11.11.11 but not 111.11.111
i'm using python

```
keyword = re.compile(r"[0-9]*[0-9]\.[0-9]*[0-9]\.[0-9]*[0-9]")
```

**the date could be at the start/end of a sentence and not have a white space but a next line before/after. how would i account for both ? as it is this will pick up up 11.11.11 but also 111.11.11111 etc :(**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\b` to match a word boundary.  For example, you could make your regular expression:

```
 re.compile(r'\b\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b')
```

I've also used `\d` to match any digit and the `{2}` suffix to match two instances of whatever came previously.  If you want to match either 1 or 2 digits in any of those cases,  you could change the `{2}` to `{1,2}`.

Answer (score 3):

`*` means "zero or more of the preceding token". Therefore your regex will match anything from `1.1.1` to `999999.999999.99999` etc.

You can be more specific like this:

```
keyword = re.compile(r"\b[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\b")
```

The `\b` word boundary anchors make sure that the numbers start/end at that position. Otherwise you could pick up substring matches (matching `34.56.78` in the string `1234.56.7890`, for example).

Of course, you'll need to validate whether it's actually a plausible date separately. Don't use regexes for this (it's [possible but cumbersome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149524/regular-expression-to-find-separator-dots-in-formula/5164598#5164598)), rather use the [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module's [`strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) classmethod.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `?` instead of `*` as a wildcard.

The `?` matches 0 or 1 instances of the previous element. In other words, it makes the element optional; it can be present, but it doesn't have to be.

This will match both `1.1.1` and `11.11.11`, but not `1111.1111.1111`:

```
keyword = re.compile(r"\b[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]?[0-9]\b")
```

Comment: sorry but that does match 111.1.111 because its not explicitly saying not more at the ends.

Comment: @Ryan It will not _match_ `111.1.111`, because `re.match` only matches  the entire string. However, `re.search` will still return a match, and that's what you meant, I guess.